# JSON unable to accept json_encode() arrays

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am sending a simple array from my PHP file,

```
//example.php
if(0){
    return json_encode(['status'=>false, 'message'=>'Please enter a username']);
}
```

and in my `ajax.js` I have everything working, including the XHR object, and event handlers. All is find, except this line.

```
 // ...
 var x = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
 console.log(x); 
// ...
```

But, I am getting the following error.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I don't understand this. All the code is correct. Before using JSON, I used to pass from values from PHP using `echo 'ok'` and just do `if(xmlhttp.responseText) == 'ok` and it worked fine, but not with json

Comment: You'll have to look at whatever response your PHP actually returned (leading/trailing garbage/HTML). And `if(0){` probably doesn't help.

Comment: Nope, the PHP file is clean. I checked. There is nothing being sent except the array.

Comment: Can you post the full response of the PHP file? Get it from your browsers console.

Comment: @Scopey the error is the full response, though there are two empty string being displayed before and after the error. both double-quoted empty strings.

Comment: Try running trim() or [filter out empty elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in your array.

Comment: Now the empty strings are gone, but the error is still there.

Comment: Hmm, what happens in the console if you `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` as the first line in your success callback/event?

Comment: I just get `""` empty double strings @Jaxo

Comment: anyone has any idea.

Comment: You use `return` instead of `echo` I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- you use `return` which does not print anything to the output wheras `echo` actually prints text. Try using:
- `if(0)` will always fail, so you will **never** print anything. You should use `if(1)` as trivial test. It is possible that you're PHP code can fail, but in that case you better also return an JSON formatted error message.

Something like:

```
if(test) { //test means you can do the action
    //do action
    echo json_encode(['return' => 'ok','result' => 'foobar']);
} else {
    echo json_encode(['return' => 'error']);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it turns out I should have used echo. the `(0)` part was written here by mistake. But, one problem I have is that, echo outputs data to the browser before actually javascript can for example redirect the page. Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: What output? The fetched page? It's rather hard to debug this without any page source...

Comment: I mean, for example, in the code you have given. if there is no error, I can see `{return:ok, result:foobar}` in the page, because the javascript can decode the json format and do some action, like page redirect. So, in the registration page, I have, people will see the serialized data no matter what, because echo just outputs it to the browser.